# download all tweets of a user to csv

Tags: javascript, api, csv, twitter

of a University Project I want to download all tweets as well as the corresponding comments (if that would not be possible the last 100, 200 etc would be enough) and save them in a CSV file.

The Information I need to have are `id, name, type, referring_to, date, time, user, likes, retweets, text`

the referring to section should identify where a comment is belonging to. If the tweet is not connected to anything nothing the value should be -1.

The major problem I see is ,except for a long time waiting for the CSV to be created, that there is no id which shows where a comment belongs to. All other APIs I took a look at (like YouTube, Amazon and even StackExchange) don't provide that kind of information.

The reason I need these 2 "layers" is because the project approach is to visualize Comments in another easier way.

Maybe one of you has an Idea.

Comment: Twitter doesn't have a "comments" feature, so it's not clear what you are talking about.  Also, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Okay yeah actually I mean answering on a tweet. I thought it was clear what I mean.

Comment: Okay, so you are talking about replies.  What's your question?

Comment: How to generally create the csv I described above. Not in detail just the general idea

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to decide whether you're going to write your own interface to the Twitter API or use someone else's.  I highly recommend that you use someone else's; you will save yourself a great deal of time and effort and you can focus on the problem you actually want to solve.

Once you've done that, you'll want to look at the **in_reply_to_status_id** property of each tweet.  This property tells you that the tweet is a reply, and tells you what tweet it's replying to.  Detailed information can be found in the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets)

As to how many people "like" the Tweet, Twitter has "Favorites", and you'd want to look at the **favorite_count** property; this tells you how many users have marked the tweet as a favorite.

A note of caution: You say you want to download "all tweet".  This isn't possible through the API.  You can get all of *your* tweets, or all of the tweets of a specific user, but you can't get every tweet.

Comment: Okay that is exactly what I meant. I just want do download every tweet or like written above the last 300 of a specific user

Comment: What you describe is possible, but the specifics of how to od it will depend on which Twitter library you choose to use.

Comment: Okay is there any library you can recommend

Comment: That would depend largely on what platform you are using for development.  Twitter maintains a list of libraries: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries